# Finding an element by a part of ID using selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

How can I find the following element while it's path  changes every hour with javascript?

```
<a onclick="" href="javascript:validatePostBack('jspx_generated_8','sendActivationRequest','prepaidActivationForm','null','y',false)" name="jspx_generated_8" id="jspx_generated_8">
    <img src="/extranet/images/req/accept.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CssSelector to select elements that the attribute 'href' contains 'prepaidActivationForm'. See java code below:
`WebElement aElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href*='prepaidActivationForm']"));`

Comment: thanks ,,, it was my fault ,,,code is running successfully

Comment: Could you accept my answer so we can close this question?